# why I don't see BIOS Flash Update option latitude 6530 after click F12

Tags: laptop, bios, dell-latitude

Hello Guys I have dell latitude e6530 I don't see BIOS Flash Update option listed after click F12

any help?

[image for Option listed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvDao.png)

Answer (score 0):

Go to this Dell site:

https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-ca/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=w3jyv

> This package provides the Dell System BIOS update and is supported on
> Dell Latitude E6530 System BIOS models that are running the following
> Operating System: Windows and DOS

Update your BIOS using this method and not from within BIOS

Download the Dell Driver Update app and try updating BIOS via the Updater App.

If this does not work, contact Dell Support.

Comment: I try to install it by USB flash after preparing the laptop restart automatic but run windows don't run progress BIOS to update. I try any method but not working. If there are any laptop don't support to update BIOS?

Comment: That was the only method Dell offered for that laptop. Some newer machines can run a Windows EXE that prepares the BIOS and drops to a text window to update. That is really just a shell around a USB updater. If the above does not work you may need to call Dell Support

Comment: Also try the Dell Updater app to update your BIOS. Numerous vendors are doing updates this way.